# Loading a JSON file into JavaScript (possibly without JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I was used to handle data using PHP + PostGreSQL and, after a SQL query, print data in table using

---

```
    while($var= pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo <<<PRINT
        <tr>
            <td>{$var['id']}</td>
            <td>{$var['name']}</td>
            <td>{$var['surname']}</td>
            <td>{$var['placement']}</td>
        </tr>
PRINT;
```

---

Now I have a similar problem but I have to handle JSon files only using JavaScript and no JQueries/AJAX syntax. I made some reasearch and found out that seems not possible to load data using JavaScript for security reasons, but it feels kinda odd since you can manipulate all kind of media-type files.. and you cannot get JSon text files from your disk.

So, is it really possible to load JSon files using JavaScript and then being able to manipulate it ciclicaly?

Comment: You can store them as JS files and load them as a proper object

Comment: What do you mean no AJAX/jQuery syntax? No matter what, at the end of the day, you're going to need to embed them somewhere that's reachable from some type of request.

Comment: Google `Javascript fetch API`.

Answer (score 0):

### Deal with files on the PC, form the browser

Maybe you should test something from the File Web API.
Search for "File" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).

### Deal with files on a server, form the browser

You publish your JSON at some URL and then GET the JSON with AJAX. 
See: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Well, depends, if you mean a local `.JSON` file you could simply use `require` to get the object, to manipulate it you could either use [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) or [klaw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/klaw)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify files with http protocols.

I paste this link, to make a mini web server https://sourceforge.net/projects/miniweb/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't access a local file directly from the browser. File should be served over a local server, specially if you are using Chrome. Since Chromes security is much tighter than Firefox or others, loading anything using xhr, Josn, Xml etc is pretty much all locked down.

you can use simply use `apache`, `python` or `node` to set up a simple local server.

Then use Fetch API. All modern browsers support [Fetch API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) except Internet NOBODY USING Explorer.

```
        fetch('/path/to/test.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => console.log(json));
```

done..! hope it helps.